# prob in implementing kmeans++ in r

Tags: r, k-means

I am actually tring to get db index for k=2:63. This problem occurs when I run kmeans in a loop otherwise it does not show error.

Here is my main function

```
for(i in 2:63) {
  print(i)
  # kmeans++ algorithm 
  r_cluster_result = kmpp(r_cluster_mat,i)
  r_cluster_data = data.frame(r_cluster_result$cluster)
  db = index.DB(x=r_cluster,cl=r_cluster_result$cluster,d=NULL,centrotypes="centroids",p=2,q=1)
  db_values = c(db_values,db$DB)
}
```

Here is my kmeans++ function code

```
kmpp <- function(X, k) {
  n <- nrow(X)
  C <- numeric(k)
  C[1] <- sample(1:n, 1)

  for (i in 2:k) {
    dm <- distmat(X, X[C, ])
    pr <- apply(dm, 1, min); 
    pr[C] <- 0
    C[i] <- sample(1:n, 1, prob = pr)

  }

  kmeans(X, X[C, ])
}
```

Error msg

```
Error in sample(1:n, 1, prob = pr) : NA in probability vector
In addition: Warning message:
In sqrt(XX + YY - 2 * XY) : NaNs produced
```

dput(X) is

[dput(x)](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3HY2LeaaBrYeUZJQ2xLTGZZMHM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: There is an `NA` in your probability vector (`pr`), this is not good.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra how can I check which one is creating problem? There are lots of data in x.

Comment: Check the content of `distmat`, there is an NA in there somewhere...

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I have edited my question. This error occurs when kmpp in a loop.

Comment: Please make your data available in an R readable format, e.g. using `dput`.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra should I attach  dput(x)  in this question?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I add the dput(x)

Comment: In the meantime, add a line inside your loop to `cat(i)` . That way you'll know which value of `i` led to failure.  I'm guessing here that when you say it works outside of a loop you tested `kmpp` for a few values of `k` but not the full range `2:63` .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I have printed cat(i) and it is showing error for different value of i in every time.But specifically test kmmp for that i there is no error. :(

Comment: Well, notice that `dm` and `pr` are independent of `i` , so whatever value you're expecting to get is not what's happening. I would recommend double-checking your code inside and outside the loop to see if there's a typo -- as well as checking to see what the actual values in `pr` are.